# When does $\mathbb{Z}_{m} × \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ form a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals

When does $\mathbb{Z}_{m}×\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ form a field? I thought that I could use proposition that say, if I and J are comaximal ideal of R, then $$\dfrac{R}{I \cap J} \simeq \dfrac{R}{I} × \dfrac{R}{J}$$ Using that we have if m and n are relatively prime then $\mathbb{Z}_{m}×\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ form a field. Is it true? For example, $\mathbb{Z}_{3}×\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ doesn't form a field since $\gcd(3,3) = 3$. I am so confused. Thanks in advance

Comment: However, $F = \mathbb{Z}_{3}×\mathbb{Z}_{17}$ form a field since $\gcd(3,17)=1$. Moreover, char$(F)=51$

Comment: Unless you're in a degenerate case with $n = 1$ or $m = 1$, this ring always has zero-divisors: $(1,0) \cdot (0,1) = (0,0)$.

Comment: More more moreover $F$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{51}$

Comment: What is a degenerate case?

Comment: Okay I understand what a degenerate case is

Comment: So it is true isn't it

Comment: No, of course not. A field does not have zero-divisors.

Comment: For non-degenerate case is it true?

Comment: Let $A,B$ be rings. If $A,B$ are nonzero, then $A \times B$ is *never* a field. Because $(1,0)$ doesn’t have an inverse.

Comment: Maybe the confusion is here: ${\mathbb Z}_{51}$ is _not_ a field (because $3 \cdot 17 = 0$).

Comment: Thank you all guys, I understand perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, I'd say pretty much never. Now what we first need to understand is that additive and multiplicative groups of a finite field aren't isomorphic, in fact, they don't even have the same cardinality (Multiplicative group excludes 0).

Now a finite field of order $n$ exists if and only if $n$ is a prime power ($n=p^h$ for some prime $p$ and $h\in \mathbb N$). We refer to this field as ${\rm GF}(n)$, as in Galois Field of order $n$. That being said, its additive group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p\times ... \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ ($h$ times) and its additive group is a cyclic group of order $n-1$, thus isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{n-1}$.

Comment: *Please* strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).